# How to deploy three div elements next to each other on one line?

Tags: html, css

I have the following problem. I have a div, which surrounds three other div elements.
I want these three div elements to be placed side by side on one line and only average (div 2) to be visible.
I have tryed   display: inline and float: left; on these three div's with no luck. 
The elements are positioned one below the other, each on a new line. I want these div's to 
be on one line. This is shown in the picture. I would appreciate any help.
This is me css code:

```
html, body{
    height: 100%;
}

#linksHolder {
    width: 50%;
    height: 25%;
    margin: 0px auto;
    overflow: hidden;
    text-align: center;
}
.holderItem {
    border: 1px solid red;
    width: 99%;
    height: 98%;
    float: left;
    display: inline;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/zono/nGC2P/

Best regards.[image]

Average div is div 2 i want div 2 to be visible instead div 1 that is visible in this momment.

Comment: what do you mean by "and only average (div 2) to be visible?"

Comment: Would need to see some code. You can set divs to inline then float them left but always need some code in question so we can investigate. What do you mean by average (div 2) to be visable. Sounds like a slider to me

Comment: Yes. This is slider. I'm using jQuery UI. Code is long. I will create jsfiddle.

Comment: Yes, this sounds like you need to be looking for a JavaScript or jQuery slideshow plugin

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Does this help?

http://jsfiddle.net/nGC2P/73/

When you set 3 Divs to 99% each it won't fit.
I have set them to 32% (+ border), and set visibility to "hidden"

```
.holderItem {
    border: 1px solid red;
    width: 32%;
    height: 98%;
    float: left;
    display: inline-block;
}
.holderItem:first-child { visibility: hidden; }
.holderItem:last-child { visibility: hidden; }
```

PS: uppps... pretty late

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can try to set the width of .holderItem to 30%, that way you can have the 3 elements in one line.

If you want to hide the div 1 and 3 you can add a display property (or visibility) combined with first-of-type and last-of-type.

http://css-tricks.com/almanac/selectors/f/first-of-type/

Answer (score -4):

You're going to have to apply positions to your elements:

Like this [jsfiddle.net](http://jsfiddle.net/9patj/9/)

```
#div1{
    float:left;
    width:215px;
    background-color:red;
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0px;
}

#div2{
    float: left;
    width: 300px;
    background-color: red;
    bottom: 0px;
    left: 216px;
}

#div3{
    float:right;
    width:215px;
    background-color:yellow;
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 0px;
    right: 0px;
}
```

Comment: Float and position absolute rarely if ever go together.

Comment: I dont know how you can come up with this answer and fiddle without seeing his code. Creating your version of the problem obviously isnt going to be hard to fix